# Get part of hex string

Tags: python, hex

I have this code:
Hexline - string in hex (080a00000135627c43784... etc)

```
Date = Hexline[:16]
Prio = Hexline[16:2]
Date = "0x"+Date
DecDate = long(Date, 16)
print 'date = %s' % DecDate
print 'prio = %s' % int(Prio, 16)
```

1. I get first 16 symbols and convert it in BigInt
2. I need to get next two symbols after "Date" from "Hexline" and convert it to Decimal.

But on step 2 i got "invalid literal for int() with base 16 '' " error. (Prio = '') 
 What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Prio` will always end up to be an empty string.  You probably mean

```
Prio = Hexline[16:18]
```

The number after the colon is the stop index of the substring, not its length.